# bat file commands - how to cut file and replace existing file

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command, xcopy

I need to swap out a file with data (original) to a dummy file with no data. I need to switch back and forth between these tow files on a regular basis. As a safe way to not delete files, I thought the best way would be to rename the original file, then copy the dummy file over to the same directory as the original. WHen i want to switch back I would simply 'cut' the dummy file and then rename the original to its original name. My current scripts look something like this:

```
pushd "F:\BIO4\Etc\"
ren "omake01.esl" "omake01-OG.esl"
COPY "I:\Mod Switcher\Blank Omake\omake01.esl" "F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01.esl"
```

1st part done. I have renamed the original so that the dummy file can be copied over to its place in the original directory. Now I want to revert this, and move the dummy file back to where it came from, and then rename my original back to its orignal name:

```
xcopy /y "F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01.esl" "I:\Mod Switcher\Blank Omake\omake01.esl"
pushd "F:\BIO4\Etc\"
ren "omake01-OG.esl" "omake01.esl"
```

The problem is here that the file is not being cut, simply copied and then the file is not renamed afterwards. The following output comes up in console:

```
C:\Users\Anon\Desktop 3>xcopy /y "F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01.esl" "I:\Mod Switcher\Blank Omake\omake01.esl"

F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01.esl
1 File(s) copied

C:\Users\Anon\Desktop 3>pushd "F:\BIO4\Etc\"

F:\BIO4\Etc>ren "omake01-OG.esl" "omake01.esl"
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
```

How can i make this easier or actually even work ?

Running Windows & 64 bit

Comment: move /y did the trick!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of copying and renaming, just move the file which is effectively Cut & Paste.

```
MOVE /Y "I:\Mod Switcher\Blank Omake\omake01.esl" "F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01.esl"
```

The `/Y` switch just stops the "confirm overwrite" prompts.
Do `move /?` to see all the switches.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is OLD thread, but as it is likely to be of aid to someone limited in experience as I.

As stated above you can MOVE the file, but according to MOVE /? **you can also rename it using the destination option.**

MOVE /Y "I:\Mod Switcher\Blank Omake\omake01.esl" "F:\BIO4\Etc\omake01-OG.esl"

I tested with

move "test2.txt" ".\test\test3.txt"

Which moves test2.txt into the test subdirectory and renames it test3.txt successfully.